# Lists of shared items VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, reference

There is any way to have two List(Of T) with shared items, I mean if I modify one item in one list the same item gets modified in the other list.

Comment: If `T` is a reference type and you add the same reference to two lists that will happen automatically.

Comment: what you have tried? may i see some snippet?

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve. In programming a lot of things are possible, and there are even more ways to accomplish every one of them, but only a little subset actually makes sense and/or has value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `List(Of T)` if `T` is reference type (ie. instance of some class), then it is possible. otherwise, for `Integer`, `String`, `Double` it is not.

for example take:

```
Dim list1 = new List(Of Cat)
Dim list2 = new List(Of Cat)

Dim cat1 = new Cat()
list1.add(cat1)
list2.add(cat1)
```

now assume we mutate cat in one of the list

```
list1.first.color = "white"
System.WriteLine(list1.first.color)
System.WriteLine(list2.first.color)
```

you will see that in output that both are *white*. but imagine you had a `List(Of Integer). then changing at one place would not have affected the other.

### Edit

to define exactly when changes in one list will get reflected in the other, i used terms like `reference`, `instance` etc. also people have discussed topics like `Nullable(Of T)`, `Immutability` etc. so yes, precise definition of *exactly* when this magic happens and when doesnot is a bit broad. so if you happen to fall in those edge cases then well ask again with some code sample. but for general usage knowing this is sufficient that class instances will change at both places, Integer, String, Boolean, double etc will not.

Comment: `String` _is_ a reference type ;)

Comment: Nullable(Of Integer) is a reference type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's tricky with a String. It is a reference type, but it's not possible. :)

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, otherwise it looks more like a comment.

Comment: @Neolisk: [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a reference- but a value-type since it's a struct.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yep you are right, I got confused by being able to assign Nothing to it. In this case one can make their own Nullable(Of T) class.

Comment: has anyone considered the remote possibility that the OP is a beginner or someone not too familiar with the references and structs and nullability and and posibility? is being a beginner a crime on this site that we **need** to punish him with every detail of VB and dot-net and clr? for godsake he asked a simple question. for which he expcects a simple answer. seriously you guys think he is talking about `List<Nullable<T>>`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perfectly possible with objects as the T will be a reference, but you have to use mutable types. Immutables will effectively create a new object upon modification which may not provide the results you require.

The other thing to remember is that when passing references around, those references themselves are passed by value.

Having two lists where altering one alters the other is probably going to introduce weird side-effects into your code.

Try to rely on safe, immutable objects where possible and require explicit code (i.e. readable and thus maintainable).